# Spring cloud contract error 'expecting to be equal to <generated> closure

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have my contract written in groovy.
I have request body with UUID and response is (another, random) UUID.

```
Contract.make {
    description "Should create configuration"
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/configuration'
        body(
       childBranch: $(consumer(regex(uuid()))),       
    )
        headers {
            header (HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, new NotToEscapePattern(~'application/json;.*charset=UTF-8.*')) 
        }
    }
    response {
        status HttpStatus.CREATED.value()
        body(${consumer(regex(uuid()))})
    }
}
```

Running gradle task `generateContractTests`
Produces java class that has

```
    assertThat(responseBody)
.isEqualTo("shouldConfigure$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5@6a1d0a91");
```

Running tests in this class produces

```
Expecting:
 <""61af388b-d4f8-4eff-ad84-3cb8720138cb"">
to be equal to:
 <"shouldConfigure$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5@6a1d0a91">
but was not.
```

What is wrong with my contract? How to properly write and run contract for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cześć :) You shouldn't call the `NotToEscapePattern` really. The problem is that in the response you have `body(${consumer(regex(uuid()))})`, and you should have `body($(producer(regex(uuid()))))`

Comment: right, changed header to     contentType(applicationJson()) and it works.